# In which format bitcoin protocol send message?

Tags: protocol

I'm writing a small p2p network and I don't know if I have to transmit message (between nodes) in clear text or in another format ? How is it for bitcoin protocol ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **in clear text or in another format?  How is it for bitcoin protocol?**

In binary. With numbers mostly in little-endian byte-order. Over TCP with a conventional target port number.

The details are at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation

For example:

> ### Message structure
>
> | Field Size | Description | Data type | Comments |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 4 | magic | uint32_t | Magic value indicating message origin network, and used to seek to next message when stream state is unknown |
> | 12 | command | char[12] | ASCII string identifying the packet content, NULL padded (non-NULL padding results in packet rejected) |
> | 4 | length | uint32_t | Length of payload in number of bytes |
> | 4 | checksum | uint32_t | First 4 bytes of sha256(sha256(payload)) |
> | ? | payload | uchar[] | The actual data |

Unless message size and volume is important, I would instead use JSON in UTF8 for any protocol I create. You should make your own evaluation.

You might also want to consider the [Gossip protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gossip_protocol)

Comment: Thank you ! What are the benefits of using binary instead of json/text ?

Comment: Compactness of data on the wire